# Getting current URL or current view in $$SearchTemplateDefault?

Tags: lotus-domino

I would like to display a title in my $$SearchTemplateDefault based on the name of the view that is being displayed.   I tried @ViewTitle but that did not seem to work.  The view name is in the URL.  Is here any way to get to the URL or the view name in the $$SearchTemplateDefault form?

I also tried HTTP_Referer but that shows the referring URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you are looking for is called PATH_INFO. Just create a computed for display field with that name and formula @thisvalue or PATH_INFO

A list of all CGI- variables that can be used can be found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TABLE_OF_CGI_VARIABLES_3561.html)

The code for the view- title (computed text or cfd- field) could then be something like:

```
_viewNames := "View1" : "View2" : "View3";
_viewTitles := "View Title 1" : "View Title 2" : "View Title 3";

_path := @URLDecode( "Domino" ; PATH_INFO );
REM "Alternatively use this, as this is already decoded...";
_path := Path_Info_Decoded;

_viewName := @Left( @RightBack( _path ; "/" ) ; "?SearchView" ) );
@Replace( _viewName ; _viewNames ; _viewTitles )
```

ATTENTION: You have to List all possible Aliases of a view to be sure...